# Jquery Check if Value Input is in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jive

I want to check if my array contains the Value Input, i want something like that, anyone have an idea on how to do that ?

```js
if(jQuery.inArray($('#ValueInputTitle').val, variableValueInput) !== -1)
 {
    console.log("is in array");}
 else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

Comment: `val` is a function so use `val()`, assuming `variableValueInput` is an array you have a typo

Comment: `variableValueInput.indexOf($('#ValueInputTitle').val()>=0)`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ check this..complete guide is there on jquery page...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
if(jQuery.inArray($('#ValueInputTitle').val(), variableValueInput) !== -1)
    {
    console.log("is in array");}
    else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

Comment: Firstly please explain your answers to the OP in order to educate them. Just providing code helps no one in the long term. Also note that this issues is a very basic typo, which should be closed as such.